# What are good algorithms for virtual machine benchmarking?

Tags: algorithms, benchmarking

I am comparing execution efficiency of the same code compiled to JVM and Node, locally and on AWS Lambda. Not looking for precision, but just a rough notion of performance in difference virtual machines and execution environments.

I started with Fibonacci flavors (recursive, tail recursive, iterative, memoized, ...) are there any algorithms that would be particularly adequate for systems benchmarking?

Comment: The same benchmarks that are suitable for "real" machines, would be my guess.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best forum for this question. Perhaps stackoverflow is better.